# Way to change voice type AoG bot

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, ssml

Is there any way to change the voice type of the Actions on Google bot if I have voice simples or soft to dubbing text?
Maybe using 
[SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml)
?

Answer (score 3):

On Actions on Google, you can go to Invocations and choose a type of voice.

[image]

You can use SSML too to change the pitch and a handful of other options:

[Actions on Google | SSML `<prosody>`](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml)